# bullet chart in echarts4r

Tags: r, echarts4r

I want to create bullet charts with `{echarts4r}`. What I have is this:

```r
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

mtcars[1:5,] |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |>
  mutate(total = mpg + qsec) |>
  arrange(desc(total)) |>
  e_charts(model) |>
  e_bar(mpg, stack = "grp", barWidth = "90%", barCategoryGab = "20%") |>
  e_bar(qsec, stack = "grp") |> 
  e_bar(gear, stack = "grp2", barWidth = "45%") |> 
  e_flip_coords()
```

How can I put the third `e_bar()` in front of the other stack?

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an example solution [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmuhgE4QDmFApqYQOQCGAHhAM70A0x6L7ACsAjQwtQqhIkwATxDUGbABaMAJsADu9HrAC-xHd3TZqNaCvHaIAYxgNSwAK5mAStStgt6A8WYBBVmwWkiqMYIyEANr0vlyw9ABCsfQAwkkAIkkAovQAuvqGsNL-7EFSsvJxAG6M2A7UXNp8bAAyjABG1NilkgBmwKQAtqGidHFI1bXUOgCkniR6XgVstBDUgbAR2hKSsNCMAxUpwAMgxpAwsM6h9QWSMnIMbYykDTuwT6QA4owEcQC0AGYAAxA2a3EgfADqEBUYEUhAAjEDwegAF6I5HadAhMKRBFIziwACcABZCUSAOyEikADkJADYaTkURgsLgIL9tm8JnUAGL9IZgEaEAAUEwAlAgAHywCawADUcVmWN02m8ki5JD2BwY_GwjGg0GoKlgyWOp2o5zgV1Erx290ObCsw1odskbGkAzaODsbg8LLYEGMIkIYFIdQDnu92AAyhBURUIsDCQBWZkqj1enAAeR6PWWYEi9EBoNiQPTb3RsAATJi3jjwhsiSnycjiW2iW2aWmWZgcHhujsedR-YMXaMxTVJfAZXLFfRlW8FvNwZr0NrDvxGGwOL3yo9nm6Ic9obD4bAU3WdmwwlYANYMTBhbBH7GhRsRCltr_U79_vKSOqJBrrs-yHJ8WAqK-GD7nEHzQVCMJwoQl4BreD5xE-NTQQ2eItrACL4YRhLEQRaZqquKobgwmTMFYnTBv6KoOgeLwsohZ4oVe7roY-wDPjh754SRRGiSJAHzMQeQ6AA3EAA)

and adapted it to `{echarts4r}`

```r
library(echarts4r)

df1 <- 
  data.frame(
    type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    achieved = c(110, 94, 97, 78, 68),
    target = c(95, 90, 90, 90, 100),
    pass = c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70),
    good = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15),
    excellent = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15)
  )

df1 %>% 
  e_charts(type) %>% 
  e_bar(achieved, name = "Completion Rate", barGap = "-300%", barWidth = 10, z = 10) %>% 
  e_scatter(target, name = "Planned Completion Rate", symbol = "rect", silent = TRUE, symbolSize = c(30, 5), symbolOffset = c(0, -10), symbolRotate = 90, z = 20, color = "#000") %>% 
  e_bar(pass, name = "Pass", barWidth = 50, stack = "total") %>% 
  e_bar(good, name = "Good", barWidth = 50, stack = "total") %>% 
  e_bar(excellent, name = "Excellent", barWidth = 50, stack = "total") %>% 
  e_flip_coords() %>% 
  e_legend(icon = "roundRect")
```

[image]